# How to delete the elements with the date except 2020 from csv file with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a csv file which has 3 columns. The first one is session_id, second one is item_id and last one is date. I am trying to delete the rows which does NOT have 2020 as date. Because I want to work on only 2020 dated data.

I did some research but I couldn't find any clear information.

This is my code so far;

```
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv('purchases.csv')
dataset.info() #no null value, no missing data, nothing to drop
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
#if your date column's type is string-object:
#df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df=df[df['your_date_column'].dt.year == 2020]
```